# Laravel Composer sees wrong version of PHP

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to update Laravel from 9 to 10. I've followed the upgrade documentation and when I hit composer update, it gave me this error:

```
Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.28.
```

In the composer.json I already changed the php version on two places:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1.0",
},
```

and

```
"config": {

    "platform": {
        "php": "8.1.0"
    }
},
```

When I check my PHP with:

```
php -v
```

It shows that I'm using the correct version of PHP.

```
PHP 8.1.17 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2023 19:20:16) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.17, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

I also cleared all the caches to Laravel and tried with:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
[ErrorException]
  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.28.
```

I've investigated even more and I found out when I try with this command:

```
composer -vvv about
```

The first line of the result looks like this:

```
Running 2.2.9 (2022-03-15 22:13:37) with PHP 8.0.28 on Linux / 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64
```

So, this means somehow Composer still runs PHP 8.0, instead of PHP 8.1.

How can I force Composer to use the proper version of PHP?

Comment: Linux, windows, macOS... It makes a difference in this case :). If linux: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-tell-and-force-composer-to-use-a-specific-php-version-such-as-7-x-or-8-x/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you use php artisan serve?

when yes try `/usr/bin/php artisan serve`
this should start php 8.1.17

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I know, Composer does not use Artisan, so how should running your command help when `composer update`  shows an error message?

Comment: Excellent answer and this solved my issue. When I run your written command and after that I tried with composer -vvv about, it actually shows the right version of PHP and I got no errors anymore. Thank you very much!